# ffmpeg filter_complex trim out-sync

Tags: ffmpeg

command line:

`ffmpeg -i <INPUT> -filter-complex "<FILTER_COMPLEX>" -map "[ofa]" -map "[ofv]" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 test.mp4`

`FILTER_COMPLEX` content:

```
[0:v]split=3[sv1][sv2][sv3];
[0:a]asplit=3[sa1][sa2][sa3];
[sv1]trim=start=200:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ov1];[sa1]atrim=start=200:duration=5[oa1];
[sv2]trim=start=300:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ov2];[sa2]atrim=start=300:duration=5[oa2];
[sv3]trim=start=400:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ov3];[sa3]atrim=start=400:duration=5[oa3];
[ov1][ov2][ov3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[ofv];
[oa1][oa2][oa3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[ofa]
```

As a result, the output video sounds are out of sync, and the video is redirected to 00:00:00, but the sound remains at the original time position.

Therefore, how to use ffmpeg to intercept several clips from a video, recombine them into a new video file, and keep the sound and picture synchronized.

---

I tried with `[sa1]atrim=start=200:duration=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[oa1]` but an error:

```
Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_atrim_4' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_setpts_5' filter input pad 0 (video)

Cannot create the link atrim:0 -> setpts:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: `atrim, asetpts`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов thanks very well, it works for me.